# How to implement CANDIDATE key in any MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to implement Candidate key in my SQL table.

My table has columns `id, city, state`

How to make candidate key on city and state columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_key` (`city`, `state`);
```